# How to download fMath plugin for TinyMCE editor

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, tinymce, tinymce-4

I wanted to download fMath plugin for TinyMCE editor for writing math equations on this editor. So I went to this [link](https://pluginza.com/plugins/fmath-equation-editor) and it says:

"Download plugin from developer [website](http://www.fmath.info/)".

But when I go to the developer website I don't see any link for downloading the plugin.

I wonder if you guys have used this plugin, just let me know how to access the download link from it's official website.

Or I would really appreciate any alternative way to get the plugin...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on https://github.com/dimakorotkov/tinymce-mathjax

This plugin using MathJax library for rendering math font.

This plugin compatible with TinyMCE 5 and MathJax 3.